# How can I escape all non-alphanumeric characters in AWK?

Tags: string, awk, escaping

I inherited a very large AWK script that matches against .csv files, and I've found it does not match some alphanumeric characters, especially `+ ( )`.

While I realize this would be easy in sed:

```
sed 's/\([^A-z0-9]\)/\\\1/g'
```

I can't seem to find a way to call on the matched character the same way in AWK.

For instance a sample input is:

```
select.awk 'Patient data +(B/U)'
```

I would like to escape the non-alphanumeric characters, and turn the line into:

```
Patient\ data\ \+\(B\/U\)
```

I have seen some people pass very obscure non-alphanumeric characters as well, which I would like to escape.

Comment: You can use `gsub` on the argument before processing it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: gsub is a good idea, I just don't know how to reference the pattern `[^A-z0-9]` in the replacement part. \1 doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to show a minimum reproducible example. A few lines of your script and what lines are you trying to match with `Patient data +(B/U)`

Comment: It sounds like you should just be using string instead of regexp matching rather than trying to make your regexps behave as if they were strings. If you explain WHAT you're trying to do rather than HOW you're trying to do it, we can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/, "\\\\&", arg)
```

Comment: `echo 'Patient data +(B/U)' | awk 'gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/, "\\&",$0)1'` gives `&Patient&data&&&B&U&&`

Comment: awk has to take 2 passes on the replacement string with the first pass being to convert escape sequences like `\n` and `\t` to literal newline and tab characters. Any other char preceded by `\\` is just a literal char. So `\&` after that first phase is just `&`. If you write `\\&` then it becomes `\&` which is how you get a literal `&` into the replacement. If you write `\\\&` then that first `\t`->`<tab>` phase turns it into `\&` which again is just a literal `&`. When you add that final backslash `"\\\\&"` the first phase strips every other backslash to `\\&` which means a backslash then `&`

Answer (score 0):

the gnu variant has more feature,

```
awk '{n=gensub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"\\\\&","g"); print n}' d.csv
```